# url regex without http://www

Tags: regex, url

i need a url regex which validates the url string **without** `http://www.`  or `https://www.`

any ideas?

Comment: give an example of the string you have and the string you want to extract ... or do you want to validate if the string is an url but does not start with http://www.?

Comment: It seems clear to me. OP wants a url regex pattern that doesn't match "http://www.". @fusion Why not take an existing one and remove that match from the beginning of the pattern?

Comment: He could have also meant a regex that strips `http://www.` from a URL. Since he doesn't specify a use case and apparently spent less than 10 seconds writing the question, it's hard to tell.

Comment: apologies for not being clear. i want the regex to validate the url string but without `http://www.` it should only validate `google.com` not `http://www.google.com`

Comment: Hi Fusion, do your URLs have ports, parameters, etc.?

Comment: Do you want to be able to extract URLs from a string, like gmail chat does, without having to specify 'http://' or 'www.'?

So for instance `boobi.es` would be turned to [boobi.es](boobi.es)?

I forsee a lonnnnng regex.

Comment: What if a website requires the `www` subdomain to be valid? Ex. `www.example.com/` serves a page, but `example.com/` 404's.

Comment: @lunivore, no.

@kevin, yes something like that.

Comment: @sigint, i'm not removing `http://www.`. it'd be programmatically appended to the url which the user enters in the textbox. i don't want the user to enter `http://www.`

Comment: So run your regular expression against "http://www." + what_the_user_enters. Hope you don't mind excluding https URIs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would probably be a good idea to keep the `www`'s intact in order to preserve the sub-domain. A regex pattern like this:

`^([a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+.*)$`

would match a URL that is not prefixed by a protocol (`http://`,`https://`,`ftp://`,etc).

Comment: thank you! as i said i'm not removing the www. it would be appended to the url which the user enters in the textbox.

Comment: That regex would allow silliness like subdomain.realdomain.Hambone^&&#$@$%^&* which wouldn't qualify.

Comment: @fusion What if `example.com` doesn't have a `www` subdomain? You shouldn't blindly prepend the `www`'s. 
@Joel Etherton You are correct, this regex pattern would be VERY liberal when dealing with (what should be) GET parameters.

Comment: also doesn't allow hyphens