# Scrape mp4 file from a URL?

Tags: php, html, ffmpeg, web-scraping

I am running ffmpeg on my server and am using it with PHP. I was wondering if it was possible to enter a URL of a web page and have it search the source code for a .mp4 file. Then use that as the uploaded file in the HTML form and process it with PHP. I would also like to be able to scrape other data found on the page.

Can someone recommend a good tutorial or lesson for scraping data by just entering a URL in an HTML form? Or just answer my question if it's simple. I am a bit of a noob at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite a tall order and this won't be a complete answer, but a place for you to start...

**Retrieving data from a url**

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

This is from => http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Basically, it download the contents of a web page and stores the resulting text in the variable `$homepage`, then outputs it.

NOW!  Instead of outputting your variable, you will want to instead look for the string ".mp4", but it's not that simple.  You will have to use regular expressions.

**Have a look at**

[Regular expression pattern to match url with or without http://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427530/regular-expression-pattern-to-match-url-with-or-without-http-www)

You need to match URI's with .mp4 at the end.

**For example**

```
<?php
$subject = "abcdef";
$pattern = '/^def/';
preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,3), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

**Will produce**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => def
            [1] => 0
        )
)
```

You can use this same behavior and functionality for `preg_match` and retrieve all the hits you got for all .mp4 files on the page.  **In the code provided from the link above, you will have to modify the PATH portion and include .mp4 at the end**

Once you have the url to the MP4 file, you need to check if it has http(s) in front of it.  If it doesn't, that means it a *relative path*.  If this is the case, you need to parse the url to prepend the absolute path on the relative path to get the full URL to the MP4 file.  Then you can use `file_get_contents` again to download the mp4 file and do as you wish.

**Conclusion**

This isn't a complete answer with code, but it is a method on how you can accomplish what you wish.  If you need further guidance, I can edit and include more information.

Comment: Thank you! Luckily, the pages I'm scraping have "http" in front of the file in the src attribute. I will let you know if and when I need further guidance.