# How to capture the part of URL after .com in regex?

Tags: regex

I've come up with the following regular expression to match the valid url.

```
^(?:(ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z]+\.){0,1}(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+){1}(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})?$
```

Which matches (ftp|http|https) optional, domain name without .com or anything but also I want to capture everything that come after .com.

The above regex validates `http://stackoverflow.com` or `localhost` or `google.com` but not `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match remaining URI you can add `\S*` in the end:

`^(?:(ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z]+\.){0,1}(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+){1}(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})?(\/|\/\w\S*)?$`

But to parse various components of URL it is much better to use [**`built-in parse_url function.`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

**Alternate to validate local urls:**

`^(?:(ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\.){0,1}(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+){1}(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})?(\/|\/[\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]*)?$`

*eg.: 172.18.11.178*

**Demo:** http://regex101.com/r/vV0sB5

Comment: Regex or `parse_url` function?

Comment: try `https://www.debuggex.com/` and paste your regex in the first textbox and run some tests.

Comment: But you can see regex101 says `localhost.` is a valid url but its not.

Comment: But that problem is there even with your original regex: http://regex101.com/r/wV0kI5

Comment: And that is precisely the reason `parse_url` function is preferred option.

Comment: No. `https://www.debuggex.com/r/TofaCPnUw93Emg1a` - it say "does not  match" if you use `localhost.`

Comment: Also if you an extensive regex for matching any URL see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6427654/548225

Comment: awesome, Almost there. Only one minor issue `localhost/` becomes an invalid url as you are expecting atleast valid word after `/`. How to fix this?