# Modify Regex to Also Match IP Address

Tags: regex, validation

I currently use [this regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427530/regular-expression-pattern-to-match-url-with-or-without-http-www?lq=1) to validate URLs:

`^([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,4})(\:0*(?:6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]))?(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?$`

It matches a fairly long list of URLs:

```
google.com
google.com#a1
google.com?abc=123
google.com:80
google.com:80#a1
google.com:80?abc=123
google.com:80/test
google.com:80/test#a1
google.com:80/test?abc=123
google.com:80/test?abc=123#a1
www.google.com
www.google.com#a1
www.google.com?abc=123
www.google.com:80
www.google.com:80#a1
www.google.com:80?abc=123
www.google.com:80/test
www.google.com:80/test#a1
www.google.com:80/test?abc=123
www.google.com:80/test?abc=123#a1
www.www.google.com
www.www.google.com#a1
www.www.google.com?abc=123
www.www.google.com:80
www.www.google.com:80#a1
www.www.google.com:80?abc=123
www.www.google.com:80/test
www.www.google.com:80/test#a1
www.www.google.com:80/test?abc=123
www.www.google.com:80/test?abc=123#a1
john:smith@google.com
john:smith@google.com#a1
john:smith@google.com?abc=123
john:smith@google.com:80
john:smith@google.com:80#a1
john:smith@google.com:80?abc=123
john:smith@google.com:80/test
john:smith@google.com:80/test#a1
john:smith@google.com:80/test?abc=123
john:smith@google.com:80/test?abc=123#a1
john:smith@www.google.com
john:smith@www.google.com#a1
john:smith@www.google.com?abc=123
john:smith@www.google.com:80
john:smith@www.google.com:80#a1
john:smith@www.google.com:80?abc=123
john:smith@www.google.com:80/test
john:smith@www.google.com:80/test#a1
john:smith@www.google.com:80/test?abc=123
john:smith@www.google.com:80/test?abc=123#a1
john:smith@www.www.google.com
john:smith@www.www.google.com#a1
john:smith@www.www.google.com?abc=123
john:smith@www.www.google.com:80
john:smith@www.www.google.com:80#a1
john:smith@www.www.google.com:80?abc=123
john:smith@www.www.google.com:80/test
john:smith@www.www.google.com:80/test#a1
john:smith@www.www.google.com:80/test?abc=123
john:smith@www.www.google.com:80/test?abc=123#a1
```

However, it does not match these URLs which, to my knowledge, are also valid:

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8#a1
8.8.8.8?abc=123
8.8.8.8:80
8.8.8.8:80#a1
8.8.8.8:80?abc=123
8.8.8.8:80/test
8.8.8.8:80/test#a1
8.8.8.8:80/test?abc=123
8.8.8.8:80/test?abc=123#a1
john:smith@8.8.8.8
john:smith@8.8.8.8#a1
john:smith@8.8.8.8?abc=123
john:smith@8.8.8.8:80
john:smith@8.8.8.8:80#a1
john:smith@8.8.8.8:80?abc=123
john:smith@8.8.8.8:80/test
john:smith@8.8.8.8:80/test#a1
john:smith@8.8.8.8:80/test?abc=123
john:smith@8.8.8.8:80/test?abc=123#a1
```

For reference, I found this one for IP addresses which seems to work well:

`^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)`

How can I tie them together? Or, is there a better regex to match all the URLs here?

Demo:

http://rubular.com/r/ufuNkHqX5G

Comment: @hwnd Which data? The sample URLs are valid URLs for websites that I want to validate for.

Comment: The regex is from http://stackoverflow.com/a/6427654/3689902.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine two regular expressions together by doing `(?:<regex1>|<regex2>)`, which means whatever matches *regex1* or *regex2*. (The `?:` means the added parentheses won't capture).

You can find a variety of regexes for URL validation online, e.g. [In search of the perfect URL validation regex](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) lists quite a few.

Comment: The parentheses are unnecessary -- simply `regex1|regex2` does it. However, if you factor out some parts, you need grouping. If regex1 is `^regex1-1$` and regex2 has a similar structure, you could refactor to `^(?:regex1-1|regex2-1)$`

Answer (score 0):

Validating an email address is a bit more complicated than validating a webpage URL.  In fact,
determining a proper regex for validating an email address seems to be a question without one definitive right answer; see [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address/1917982)

If you use PHP, you aren't limited to using a regex to validate email addresses and URLs, as the following code illustrates:

```
<?php
$url = "http://8.8.8.8";
$mess = (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))? "invalid" : "valid";
echo $mess, ": $url\n";

$email = "me@he re.com";
$mess = (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))? "invalid" :"valid";
echo $mess, ": $email\n";
```