# PHP validate string to ensure it does not contain http:// or https:// or www

Tags: php, validation, preg-match

I have the following if statement to check whether or not a string begins with http:// or https:// but I also need it to check whether it begins with www.

```
if (preg_match('#^https?://#i', $url) === 1) {
    // Starts with http:// or https:// (case insensitive).
}
```

So the following would fail:

- http://www.website.com
- https://www.website.com
- http://website.com
- https://website.com
- www.website.com

But the following would pass the validation

- website.com

How can I adapt this to check for the above?

Comment: Please check link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427530/regular-expression-pattern-to-match-url-with-or-without-http-www

Comment: There are multiple TLDs and could be numerous directories. Do you only care about any named domain on `.com`?

Comment: @chris85 - Ultimately I want to make sure that 'myurl.com' is also valid but wanted to work this out as a start point.

Comment: Okay than how about. `#(^https?://|\w+\.com$)#`

Comment: Not quite... the TLD is not important... just the http / https / www part - none of which should be present...

Comment: Oh, so no www is valid. Okay how about `#(^(https?://|www\.)`?

Comment: Awesome @chris85 - looks like that's done the trick... add it as an answer and I'll give it the tick...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the regex `#^(https?://|www\.)#i`, and here's a way to test for future URLs (command line, change `\n` to `<br>` if testing in a browser).

```
<?php
$urls = array('http://www.website.com', 'https://www.website.com', 'http://website.com', 'https://website.com', 'www.website.com', 'website.com');
foreach($urls as $url) {
    if (preg_match('#^(https?://|www\.)#i', $url) === 1){
        echo $url . ' matches' . "\n";
    } else {
        echo $url . ' fails' . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
http://www.website.com matches
https://www.website.com matches
http://website.com matches
https://website.com matches
www.website.com matches
website.com fails
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
preg_match('#^((https?://)|www\.?)#i', $url) === 1
```

Comment: Targeted string doesn't have `www` and doesn't start with `http`.

Comment: Still not quite there... `http://website.com` and `https://website.com` would still pass

Comment: This fails because you've made both parameters optional.