# Regex to linkify URLs

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I currently have the following regex to capture link text and a URL in the following format:

`[Link](http://link.com)`

`\[(.+)]\(((https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,}))\)`

When I add another expression afterwards to linkify URLs, it messes up ones in the above format.

Is there a singular regular expression to handle both cases?

`http://link.com` -> `<a href="http://link.com" target="_blank">http://link.com</a>`

`[Link](http://link.com)` -> `<a href="http://link.com" target="_blank">Link</a>`

PHP:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\[(.+)]\(((https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,}))\)/', '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$1</a>', $string);
```

Comment: Obligatory ["You can't parse HTML with regex"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1270789) link.

Comment: @KenY-N reread the question...

Comment: @frosty I would definitely not try to do this in one regex.

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427530/regular-expression-pattern-to-match-url-with-or-without-http-www) might help you match stand alone URLs.

Answer (score 2):

There's no real ways to identify an url in a string since the url syntax can be very complicated (too complicated to be clear). In other words, you must accept that something that looks like `[...](...)` stands for a link without to try to verify if the content between `(` and `)` is really an URL. *(You can always use `parse_url` after, but keep in mind that it may exclude valid urls)*.

What you are looking for is:

```
$result = preg_replace('~\[([^]]*)]\([^)]*\)~', '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$1</a>', $str);

// If you want to hunt lonely urls in your text, you can always search
// after extracting text nodes with XPath and a naive pattern like this:

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($result);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$textNodes = $xp->query('//text()');

foreach($textNodes as $textNode) {
    $textNode->nodeValue = preg_replace('~[hw](?:(?<=\bh)ttps?://|(?<=\bw)ww\.)\S+~i', '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a>~', $textNode->nodeValue);
}

$result = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Note: for better results, if you absolutely want to check the url, you can use the same pattern with `preg_replace_callback`, remove the last character of the match until `parse_url` works and perform the replacement, but it will not be very performant.

Comment: @HamZa: I added a poor way to do it.

Comment: My code was working for [...](...) though... what I meant was that doing the lonely-url preg_replace ended up breaking the the ones in the [...](...) format. I can't seem to get yours working either.

Comment: @frosty: I have edited my answer, you must now apply this last pattern only on text nodes after extracting them with XPath to avoid the problem.

Comment: I don't know what XPath is and how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you a bit:

```
/**
 * Linkify Function
 * @param $tweet
 * @return mixed
 */
function linkify_tweet($tweet)
{
//Convert urls to <a> links
$tweet = preg_replace("/([\w]+\:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/", "<a href=\"mailto:w2m@bachecubano.com?subject=WEB $1\">$1</a>", $tweet);

//Convert hashtags to twitter searches in <a> links
$tweet = preg_replace("/#([A-Za-z0-9\/\.]*)/", "<a href=\"#\">#$1</a>", $tweet);

//Convert attags to twitter profiles in <a> links
$tweet = preg_replace("/@([A-Za-z0-9\/\.]*)/", "<a href=\"mailto:w2m@bachecubano.com?subject=MSG @$1\" class=\"userlink\">@$1</a>", $tweet);

return $tweet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First deal with markdown syntax. Then catch plain links that were not processed - you may use similar regexp, but without parethesis. If you want to replace everything that looks like an url within whitespace limits (html won't match) then this will do:

`\s(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})`