# PHP validation (two conditions)

Tags: php, drupal

I am making a json validation that needs to validate url that starts with http:// or https://

```
  if(preg_match("/^[http://][a-zA-Z -]+$/", $_POST["url"]) === 0)
  if(preg_match("/^[https://][a-zA-Z -]+$/", $_POST["url"]) === 0)
```

Am I wrong in synatx, and also how should i combine both (http and https) in same statement ?

Thank you !

Comment: Hope this link will help you :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427530/regular-expression-pattern-to-match-url-with-or-without-http-www

Comment: You can use this : https://regex101.com/r/Ciafhq/1

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$_SERVER['HTTPS']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

```
 $isHttps = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `parse_url`

```
<?php
$url = parse_url($_POST["url"]);

if($url['scheme'] == 'https'){
   // is https;
}else if($url['scheme'] == 'http'){
   // is http;
}
// try to do this, so you can know what is the $url contains 
echo '<pre>';print_r($url);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
if (substr($_POST["url"], 0, 7) == "http://")
    $res = "http";

if (substr($_POST["url"], 0, 8) == "https://")
    $res = "https";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check your string starts with *http://* or *https://* without worrying about the validity of the whole URL, just do that :

```
<?php
if (preg_match('`^https?://.+`i', $_POST['url'])) {
    // $_POST['url'] starts with http:// or https://
}
```